# Custom Fields Bulk Edit

Tags: custom-field, customization, sql, bulk

I have a question.
I am running detube theme which has a custom field named "dp_video_code" in which i put my video embeded code. Recently the embeded code has change and I need to modify the video code in all posts(I need to replace the text "preview" from the code with "edit"). Is there anyway to do this without take all posts one by one?
Can I be done with a sql query? If yes what would that be?
I saw some plugins like "Custom Field Bulk edit" but it isn't what I search.
This is how the custom field looks:
[image: I need to replace the "preview" with "edit" in all posts]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST BACKUP!!!!!**

**NEXT, BE SURE THE BACKUP IS RIGHT**

Now, you can use this code in PHPMyAdmin

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'preview', 'edit') WHERE meta_key = 'dp_video_code'
```

Make sure that's the correct name of the custom field, you can check it in the `wp_postmeta` table.