# Bulk edit existing shortcode within custom field

Tags: plugins, mysql

I have a very similar question to this: [Custom Fields Bulk Edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162224/custom-fields-bulk-edit)

I would like to edit ALL of the data inside a custom field but instead of replacing values I would like to instead add an attribute to the custom field on each page. Example:

This is an existing shortcode
`[idx-listings linkid="387056" count="6"]`
I now want to add an attribute to look like this:
`[idx-listings linkid="387056" count="6" showlargerphotos="true"]` 
Is there a way of bulk apending the `showlargerphotos` attribute inside the existing shortcode without affecting the rest of the string?

Here is the custom field in the `wp_postmeta` table
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin:

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value =
replace(meta_value,'[idx-listings','[idx-listings showlargerphotos="true"');
```

As long as you've always typed the shortcode starting with `[idx-listings` and not, say, `[ idx-listings`, this will add your new attribute everywhere the shortcode has been used.

Comment: I do not have any spaces or other characters in the shortcode. I received an Unknown column error when I tried to execute the query. I also tried changing `post_content` to `Listings` with the same error. I added an image of a sample record in phpmyadmin, if that helps.

Comment: Looks like there was a typo - updated above should now work.